# Want to alert second json data array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

Here, I am getting two array of json.
I did exit after first json data to alert in ajax.
But when I am going to alert second json data, it shows "undefined".
So, How can be alert value of second json data?

My code is like,

```
$data1['month_result'] = $user_wise_performance;
$data1['total_point'] = $total_point;
$data1['total_earn_point'] = $total_earn_point;
echo json_encode($data1);
exit();
$data2['week_month_result'] = $user_wise_performance;
$data2['week_total_point'] = $total_point;
$data2['week_total_earn_point'] = $total_earn_point;
echo json_encode($data2);
exit();
```

And ajax call is like,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>grade_tasks/emp_performance",
    data:'',
    type:"GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){

        alert(data.total_earn_point);
        alert(data.week_total_earn_point);  //This is not printing the value.

    },
    error:function (){}
});
```

**(Updated):**
Here, if I am not calling exit(), I am not getting the value in ajax, 
So what can be the problem?

Comment: Why are you calling `exit`? I mean what's the purpose?

Comment: If I am not calling exit, I can not get the value in ajax.
If so, can you help or give idea without calling exit?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the first `exit();` or remove the both, i guess that your code should be like :

```
$data1['month_result'] = $user_wise_performance;
$data1['total_point'] = $total_point;
$data1['total_earn_point'] = $total_earn_point;
$data1['week_month_result'] = $user_wise_performance;
$data1['week_total_point'] = $total_point;
$data1['week_total_earn_point'] = $total_earn_point;

echo json_encode($data1);
```

Or try to use multidimensional array like **@Ohgodwhy** mentioned in comment bellow :

```
$data = 
[
    'data1' => [ 
        'month_result' => $user_wise_performance,
        'total_point' => $total_point,
        'total_earn_point' => $total_earn_point
    ],
    'data2' => [ 
        'week_month_result' => $user_wise_performance,
        'week_total_point' => $total_point,
        'week_total_earn_point' => $total_earn_point
    ]
];

echo $data;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The value of $data1['month_result'] and $data1['week_month_result'] is dufferent, so I can not do like this.

Comment: I think OP may need a multidimensional array. `$data = array('data1' => array(...data 1 stuff), 'data2' => array(...data 2 stuff'));`

Comment: Emmm maybe, thanks @Ohgodwhy i will suggest that in the answer.